JS classList not working
I have a data structure that is getting returned from apex and I am using that to render some html elements in for loop. Within this elements, I have one lightning-button that needs to be hidden based on certain conditions.
But I am getting error on classList "Cannot read proprties of null (reading 'className')". Is there something I am doing wrong or is there any other way to do this?
HTML:
<lightning-button variant="base" label="Compare" title="" name={pName} id={pId} data-id={pId} data-name={pName} value="p" onclick={handleCompare} class={pName}></lightning-button>

JS:
for(let j of this.visualPickerData){
 if(j.pDetail.length <= 1){
  const buttons = this.template.querySelector('lightning-button[name="'+j.pName+'"]');
  //const buttons = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="'+j.pId+'"]');
  //const buttons = this.template.querySelector('.'+j.planName);
  buttons.classList.add('slds-hide');
 }
}


Instead of selecting the lwc button by name we can select it by the data-id attribute like below :
for(let j of this.visualPickerData){
 if(j.pDetail.length <= 1){
  const buttons = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-button[data-id="${j.pId}"]`);
  buttons.classList.add('slds-hide');
 }
}

During rendering, name attribute is not retained by the lwc button component which causes the error.
Custom attributes are retained by the lwc button.
